# find controls from dynamically created table

Tags: asp.net

i wrote a function to create dynamic table in code behind on selectedindexchanged of checkbox,
that is when user will check 2 checkboxex 2 tables will be generated with textboxes,

Then on button click i want insert values of these textboxes in database,
for that i want to find textbox using findcontrol,but i could not find it,

So i called same function of table creation on page load,
but then it shows error that textbox is having duplicate id

Plz tell me solution for this.

thanks

Comment: Can you include code snippets? It sounds like you are creating the table twice, once on Page_Load and once on SelectedIndexChanged, resulting in duplicate IDs. In situations like this, where you create controls depending on user input, you have to recreate them before Page_Load so the postback data is captured, but destroy them before a user-initiated event could recreate them.

Answer (score 1):

When you create dynamic controls, you need to *recreate* them on every postback.

The best place to do so is in the `OnInit` event handler. The problem with doing it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler of the checkbox is that on postback they will not be re-created and can't be accessed.

See [this](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx) article for details, and perhaps read up on the [asp.net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) too.

Comment: i tried this but it is giving error to duplicate textbox ids not allows,plz give solution for this

Comment: @tina - You should give each table and other dynamically added control a _different_ ID.

Comment: Ids are also given dynamically.

Comment: @tina - And you are sure they are _different_ for each control and are also not repeated within the whole page (including other usercontrols and master page)?

Comment: yes they are not repeated,but when call same function of table creation,i think table is recreated and shows error of duplicate id

Comment: @tina - Of course, if you call the same function a couple of times, creating controls with the _same_ ID on the same request, then you will get this error. You need to create them with _different_ id's for each call.

Comment: If you are only calling this function the first time to capture postback data, instead of worrying about different IDs, destroy it before you create it the 2nd time. @Ghyath Serhal's answer is probably the right approach (more or less). For the simplest implementation, just put that code at the beginning of the table create function to make sure that any previously existing set of controls is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a div on the page with runat="Server" and give it an ID, div1 for example.
Add the table to this div but you should always write

```
div1.Controls.Clear();
```

at the first then add the table again to the div.

Comment: You can get the values of the textboxes because their values is saved in the ViewState.<br> Try it and let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: It does not matter.<br> Write div1.Controls.Clear(), then div1.Controls.Add(table);